# How can I solve "fatal: Invalid credentials" error when pushing to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

My Bitbucket password is correct because I can easily log in with this password. When I try to push a project or file to Bitbucket it shows *"Invalid credentials error"*.

```
git push -u origin master

fatal: Invalid credentials
Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org':
remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
remote: See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/username/demo.git/'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same problem with my JetBrains IDE.
It was showing a password dialog when I tried updated project sources or push my commits.

[image]

#### I solved the problem by following the below steps

- Open [App Passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/) page of personal settings on the Bitbucket
  [image]
- Click on <kbd>Create app password</kbd> and tick at least the **read** and **write** permissions of the **repositories** for the basic pull and push actions. Then give some label and submit by <kbd>Create</kbd>.
  [image]
- The generated app password should be passed in IDE
  [image]

Comment: For those looking for a solution using VS Code, the idea is pretty similar. When entering the push command a new prompt should appear at the top of the screen saying that you can press 'Enter' to push. This will fail because you are actually supposed to paste the password in the little text box that say 'Password' just above. So you just copy and paste like here and voilá.

Comment: What JetBrains IDE? JetBrains is the name of the company. They have [many IDEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs), e.g. [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm), and [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm).

Comment: @PeterMortensen It doesn't matter which one, as VCS works the same for all the IDEs listed above.

Comment: Working with VScode as well :) :)

Answer (score 296):

When prompted to log in, use your username, but instead of your usual account password, use the app password:

To get the app password

1. Go to the bitbucket.org website and log in
2. From your gear in the upper right, and click *Personal Bitbucket settings*
3. Click *App passwords* under *Access management*
4. Click <kbd>Create app password</kbd>
5. Give the app password sufficient rights (probably write on the repo at a minimum), and a label related to the application that will use the password
6. Don't forget to save that password

Comment: [MacOS] If you still facing issue after above steps, try cloning project again.

Comment: [Windows] you can remove previous bitbucket token credentials stored in your machine using CREDENTIAL MANAGER in windows

Comment: [MasOS] [Sourcetree]
7. Sourcetree -> Preferences -> Accounts
8. Create Account with new passowrd
9. Now you can clone via HTTPS

Comment: Do not forget to set needed permissions - at least Account Read and Repositories Read and Write!

Comment: Also, the username value is at general/account-settings/bitbucket-profile-settings@username

Comment: WTF, I've setup an ssh key and everything and THIS was it? Man, that's carzy, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marc please update this answer with permission settings, as 'just creating an app password' does not work without guessing the right permissions

Comment: @AlexV - I've added some comment on permissions, but if someone can't recognize what permission is necessary for pushing to a repo, I'm pretty sure they not should be doing so.

Answer (score 66):

After 2022-03-01:

> Beginning March 1, 2022, you will no longer be able to use your Atlassian account password when using Basic authentication with the Bitbucket Cloud REST API or Git over HTTPS.

1. Go to: *[Personal settings, App passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/)*
2. *Create app password*
3. Tick the necessary permissions for your needs. **Account** *Read* and **Repositories** *Read* and *Write* are needed for basic Git actions.
4. Save the password. **You can not view it again**!
5. Use the generated password to log in. You might need to use your Bitbucket username that you can find on *[Personal settings, Account settings](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/)* under "Bitbucket profile settings" (saw a post that told specifically to use the **username** don't know if it is true).

More information about app passwords is on *[App passwords](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/)*.

Comment: Now, which are the "necessary permissions for [my] needs"? Using command-line git and have no idea which permissions are necessary beyond 'repositories' read and write???

Comment: Added that part to point nr 3.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer, Mikk, to [my SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71431354/1107226)? (Just the permissions part)

Comment: This one explained it best. The page i came across in the bitbucket page only explained why it is not supported anymore but does not provide instructions on what to do next.

Comment: Isn't this backwards? They used to support OAuth, which was both user-friendly and secure. Are you sure you are not misunderstanding something, or the problem is really something else?

Comment: What specifically is the "Account Read" permission for? Doesn't the Git CLI just need to access the repository?

Comment: should be the best answer instead of the above upvoted, because of the permission settings tip: creating app password is obvious, but setting the right permissions not - only point No 3 helped me to push code to bitbucket

Answer (score 38):

After successfully creating the app password as [mentioned by Asyraf Arifin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378839/how-can-i-solve-this-invalid-credentials-problem-on-bitbucket/71404078#71404078):

To use Bitbucket "App Password" over HTTPS, you can then navigate to particular repository's path in **Terminal** then set the remote origin (for an already-cloned repository):

```
git remote set-url origin https://<Bitbucket_Username>:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/<Bitbucket_Username>/<Repo_Name>.git
```

For a new clone:

```
git clone https://<Bitbucket_Username>:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/<Bitbucket_Username>/<Repo_Name>.git
```

[image]

Comment: The use of `bitbucket_username` is confusing here. The first is the login username, the 2nd is the BB `accountname` of the repos, thus: "git remote set-url origin https://`<Bitbucket_YourLoginUsername>`:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/`<Bitbucket_Your(Company)RepoAccountName>`/<Repo_Name>.git"

Comment: If you do this, it fails. When you give your username, it fails, when you give your email, it explains the proper commands.

Comment: @YannickMussche I have added screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Thank you but I know what my username is.

Answer (score 32):

My answer is just a compilation of [Mikk Raudsepp's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378839/how-can-i-solve-this-invalid-credentials-problem-on-bitbucket/71424847#71424847) and [Anish's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378839/how-can-i-solve-this-invalid-credentials-problem-on-bitbucket/71424329#71424329).

1. Go to: *[Personal settings, App passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/)*
2. *Create app password*
3. Tick the necessary permissions for your needs.
4. Copy the generated password
5. On Terminal

   On an already-cloned project:

   ```
    git remote set-url origin https://<Bitbucket_Username>:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/<username/repoName>.git
   ```

   To clone a new project:

   ```
    git clone https://<Bitbucket_Username>:<App_Password>@bitbucket.org/<username/RepoName>.git
   ```

Why is it happening? -

> Beginning March 1, 2022, you will no longer be able to use your
> Atlassian account password when using Basic authentication with the
> Bitbucket Cloud REST API or Git over HTTPS.

Comment: do we need to write these symbols: "< >"?

Comment: nop. we don't need to.

Comment: You forgot to add <Bitbucket_Username> before <Repo_Name>.

When copying someone else's code, be sure to copy the entire code;)

Answer (score 18):

Go to *Personal settings* from the menu at the top. Click on *App passwords* and set up the permissions as required as shown below.

Copy the generated password and use it on the authentication prompt. This will resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a great deal. Expended energy for no reason whatsoever when its so easy

Answer (score 6):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

*Note in Repository Need Admin access and use updated password in terminal*

Answer (score 5):

- Go to *[Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager)* → *Windows Credentials* → *Add a generic credential*
- Fill up the fields:

  - Network address: `git:https://bitbucket.org`
  - Username:
  - App Password:

It was solved by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213891/updating-git-for-windows-credentials-for-bitbucket-app-password).

Comment: Re *"Windows Credentials"*: Isn't it [under *"Generic Credentials"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033193/)?

Answer (score 5):

If any Linux user is facing the same issue, please follow the steps given below.

1. Go to [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/)
2. Click on the [Login link](https://id.atlassian.com/login?application=bitbucket&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Faccount%2Fsignin%2F%3FredirectCount%3D1%26next%3D%252F)
3. At the bottom left, click on your avatar *icon* (your profile picture).
4. Then click *Personal settings* or you can open *[Personal settings, Account settings](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/)* directly
5. In the *Access Management* section, click on the *App password* link or you can go directly to *[Personal settings, App passwords](https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/)*
6. Click on the <kbd>Create App password</kbd> button.
7. Give the access rights as per your requirement.
8. Click on <kbd>Create</kbd>.
9. You get the pop up with a password. Copy that password somewhere in your laptop or pc (the given password will be difficult to remember).
10. Now whenever you’re are performing a Git operation, like pull or push and  if they asked for password. Instead of using your login password, you need to use the above password (one which is generated by the app password).

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had no option to create app passwords. Instead there was an option to create Personal access tokens. Now, once you create a token, you have to put the same token in place of the password. This works in Android Studio / IDEA as well as on the command prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created an app password, made sure the user is username and not email, then updated the app password in Windows' [Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager). Adding the app password in the repository path finally resolved my issue:

From:

```
https://username@bitbucket.org/...
```

To:

```
https://username:app_password@bitbucket.org/...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with this on my Mac using Android Studio. I fixed it by going into the Android Studio terminal tab and writing

```
git push
```

Then it told me that fatal: The current branch blabla_branch_name has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin blabla_branch_name
```

So I copied and pasted that into the terminal and hit enter again. This time it asked me for a password. I went into my bitbucket account online and created a new app password. Then I copied that password that it created, and pasted it into the terminal and hit enter. This seems to have reconnected the device and bitbucket and things work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting-up *passwordless* login. With this method, you will never need to worry about remembering the password again on your machine (but *don’t* use this technique on *public* computers)

See Atlassian documentation: [Set up an SSH key](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/)

Answer (score 0):

If you already generated an app password, if you are using VSCode and you have installed the Atlassian extension, then click on the git pull/push button and this will open the login dialog. Click authorize and that's it. Now you are logged in.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For Mac users:

```
cd Library/Application\ Support/SourceTree
```

Delete your username here.

You can log in again.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating ssh key and add ssh key to the bitbucket and try

Comment: Sunil Garg already suggested this. Please don't repeat answers.