# BitBucket App Password: Which permissions for git command-line access?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I understand how to create an app password for BitBucket, as discussed in [Atlassian's app password information](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71424847/1107226).

Which permissions are needed for what, though? In my case, specifically, I'm using this for command-line git for my repositories.

Immediately, I would guess that I need to check *read* and *write* under **Repositories**. What about *admin* and *delete*? And, what about **Projects** *read* and *write*?

Found this question on [BitBucket's Community: how to use app passwords](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/how-to-use-app-passwords/qaq-p/1959853?utm_source=dm&utm_medium=unpaid-social&utm_campaign=P:online*O:community*I:social_share*). Scrolling down, the OP said they figured out that they needed permissions on **Repositories** and **Projects** - but still wasn't sure if that was correct.

Where can I find exactly what these permissions represent and which I need for simple git push/pull/tag/...?

Comment: I went with the info in step 3 of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71424847/1107226), and it seems to be working so far.